# .slideDown() not working on absolute positioned div

Tags: jquery, css

https://jsfiddle.net/8mfho6ns/

Can someone tell me why the .slideDown() does not show the effect when displaying the `.cart-dropdown` div?  I am assuming it's due to the absolute position, as it works if I remove that.

Is it possible to use .slideDown on an absolute positioned element?

Comment: Change to `position: relative;` I think that will work.

Comment: `min-height` is the reason, not `position`. use `height` instead of `min-height`

Comment: @f_martinez is correct

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height` instead `height`.  Height is required for effect.

Comment: How come it seems to work only on the second click here?  http://www.purelabvitamins.com/_beta/single-product-alkapure.php  It's when you click CART at the top...

Comment: I was reviewing. Use **$('#NEWIDNAME').slideDown();** instead **$('.cart-dropdown').slideDown();**. The problem is class selector.

Comment: Remove class="cart-dropdown" to div, use id selector for css and Jquery effect